# Similar aliases in vite config for different directoreis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

It's a bit weird question so first here is an example of a setup I have to make things more clear.

```
src/test/app.js
src/test/options/config.js
src/second_test/options/config.js
src/second_test/app.js
```

inside **app.js** there is.

```
import "options/config.js
```

inside **second_test/app.js** there is.

```
import "options/config.js
```

Is there a way to have inside my vite.config two aliases that point to those configs.

```
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "first-config": "options/config.js", // this one is in test/options
      "second-config": "options/config.js" // this one is in secon_test/option
```

I know it looks weird but it's necessary to keep the setup as is.